# TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently doing a register page, using react.js and call the API with Axios using useMutation. The user can be registered but it shows an error message of [Registered failed! TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined ] but after registered it should prompt out a success message . How to solve this error.

```
const { Axios } = useContext(ApiContext);
const adduser = ({data}) => {
    Axios
    .post("/Account/Register", {
      email: data.email,
      fullname: data.fullname,
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
    });
}


  const [visible,setVisible] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    fullname: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const {mutate} = useMutation((adduser),
    { 
    onSuccess: (res) => {        
      setData({
        email: data.email,
        fullname: data.fullname,
        username: data.username,
        password: data.password,
      });
      setMessage({
        data: "Registered successfully.",
        type: "alert-success",
      });
      setTimeout(() => { 
        res.data = setLoading(true);
        history.push("/login");
      }, 3000);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      alert(`Registered  failed! ${error}.`);
    }
  });

  const onAddUser = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await mutate({ data})
}
const handleSubmit = async e =>  {
    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
  }
```

These are the codes.

This the error shown
[image]

Thank you ...

Comment: What line gives you the error? Can you put a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @Lucky Please provide more details about the error such as which line of ```data```. It would be great to help others to help you.

Comment: why did you set setLoading(true) as res.data? setLoading(true) itself is function